# Manipulate visibility by using x:Name=" as string from code

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Is it possible to manipulate visibility and other options of element by using `x:Name="` as string in VB.Net + WPF?

Things i tried?

```
Dim w As MainWindow = Application.Current.Windows(0)
'Dim nameOfControl As String = ("buttonClose")
w.[nameOfControl].Visibility = Visibility.Visible
```

And outpus is as i expected it to be, `nameOfControl` is not memeber of main window
My final result should be to manipulate(visualy) all gui elements based on database information.

Comment: Use `w.buttonClose`.

Comment: @Ed That is a private member.

Comment: is this a good place to start? 
And can you give me an example to see it on my code?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231285(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Clemens <s>Well dang me, so it is.</s> Actually the compiler's telling me it's OK.

Comment: @Ed If you call OP's code in a MainWindow method, it is accessible. Not sure about VB, but I guess outside the class it's not.

Comment: @Thomas I apologize, I got mixed up on unfamiliar VB syntax. You don't need to cast it, the code you have is already getting the type correct.

Comment: @Clemens `w.buttonClose.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` compiles for me in a static method in `Application`. I hesitate to disagree with you but that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Ed Ok, then accessibility is generated differently in VB. You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @Clemens They're both explicitly `internal` -- it's called `Friend` in VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2: Fixed a bug that caused only the first child of matching type to be returned.

Edit:  After looking into this more, it seems there are some substantial differences with extension methods in C# and VB.Net.  I have made some changes to hopefully account for those changes.

The following method will get all children of the given visual (Window is a Visual):

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic;
Imports System.Windows;
Imports System.Windows.Media;

Module VisualExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function GetVisualChildren(Of T As Visual)(parent As DependencyObject) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim child As T = Nothing
        Dim numVisuals As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
        For i As Integer = 0 To numVisuals - 1
            Dim v As Visual = DirectCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i), Visual)
            child = TryCast(v, T)

            If v IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each item As var In GetVisualChildren(Of T)(v)
                    yield Return item
                Next
            End If

            If child IsNot Nothing Then
                yield Return child
            End If
        Next

    End Function
End Module
```

This extension method must be in a Module, like shown above.

You can get a child with a specific name like so:

```
Dim window = Application.Current.Windows(0)
Dim visuals = window.GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)()
Dim nameOfControl = "NameOfControl"
Dim child = visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl)
child.Visiablity = Visibility.Collapsed
```

FrameworkElement can be replaced if you know what the type of the child control is.  Note that if there are multiple children with the same name, only one of those children will be returned.  Use Where() instead of FirstOrDefault() if you want to get them all.

Disclaimer: I am a C# programmer, all of this VB.Net code was converted from C# to VB using telerik's converter found [here](http://converter.telerik.com/).  There may be syntax or other errors in this code.

Comment: I can't say just yet that this works but as soon as i test it and fix vb.net differences i'll update my question

Comment: I have following error: for `'Dim visuals = window.GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)()'` **An exception of type System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetVisualChildren' accepts this number of arguments.**
Any idea about why this happens? Visual Studio is not showing any error untill runing application

Comment: It sounds like your code cannot access the GetVisualChildren method for some reason.  Did you place the GetVisualChildren method in a location that you can access from your code getting the child?

Comment: Do you see GetVisualChildren with Intellisense?

Comment: Now i get this: `Argument not specified for parameter 'parent' of 'Public Shared Function GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)(parent As DependencyObject) As IEnumerable(Of FrameworkElement)'.`

It seems i can access it but i need to pass more values?

Comment: After looking into VB.net some more, it seems there are some differences between extension methods in VB and C#.  I have made some edits that you should look at.  Namely, the extension method (GetVisualChildren in this case) must be declared in a Module, not a class.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can see it if i start typing MainWindow. `GetVisualChildren` pops

Comment: If you can see it locally then you can try: Dim visuals = GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)(window) instead of  Dim visuals = window.GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)()

Comment: On `  If child IsNot Nothing Then
                Return child
            End If` i get error **'Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1** I guess it's the string that i'm  sending?

Comment: It should be Yield child, not Return child.  This extension is an iterator method.

Comment: It passes all the code and now it's stuck at the end, in code `Dim visuals = GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)(window)
                Dim nameOfControl = "veleprodajaTab"
                Dim child = visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl)
                child.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`
I get a null reference exception at ** child.Visibility = Visibility.Visible**

Comment: Set a breakpoint, and check if visuals has any elements.  Also, you are certain that you have the name spelled correctly?

Comment: You are right, visuals have 'Nothing' and i have '' <Button x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="veleprodajaTab"'

Comment: window is not null is it?

Comment: No, window is not null, window is: **{ERPKerametal.MainWindow}**

Comment: I found a bug in the function that caused it to return the first child of matching type, and then stop.  When I test the method in my code it now works to get an arbitrary child by name. Please try with the fixed version of the function

Comment: Also, make sure that the window has been displayed before you try to get the visual tree.  Visual items are not initialized until their parents are, so this method will not work if the window has never been shown.

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved me. Now i'm off to learn MVVM. You are a true gem!

Answer (score 2):

(Turns out OP needs to look up arbitrary controls by string name in a loop -- which is ideally done via MVVM and a redesign, but for now the answer is walking the visual tree).

You've already pretty much got it.

```
Dim w As MainWindow = Application.Current.Windows(0)
w.buttonClose.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

When you put the `x:Name` attribute on a control, WPF gives the parent class (`MainWindow` in this case) a `Friend` property for the control that has that name. `Friend` (C# calls it `internal`) means any code in the same assembly has access to it. `w` is a reference to your `MainWindow` class, so there it is.

Therefore, assuming this code is in the same assembly as `MainWindow`, that should work.

Comment: The comented code above is the piece i'm missing, i can assign 'nameOfControl ' to be a string but i can't use 'nameOfControl ' as a string to call a w."nameOfControl ".visibility

Comment: @Thomas Are you saying you need to touch *arbitrary* child controls by name, where the name is a string? In that case Brandon Kramer's answer may be just what you're looking for after all.

Comment: @Thomas Let me actually restate that: What you need is MVVM. You're looking for a workaround to avoid MVVM, perhaps for learning curve reasons (understandable, but the pain does pay for itself lavishly in the end).

Comment: Is mvvm overkill for this kind of application? I have just googled it and it seems that i can do this with mvvm but in the end, i only need to make a `  For Each s In output
                Return s
                Dim nameOfControl = s
                Dim child = visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl)
                child.Visiablity = Visibility.Collapsed
            
            Next`
I mean, i will query the database and for each String that i get from database i want to remove visibility to that control @EdPlunkett

Comment: @Thomas I probably overstated that. Once you know MVVM, it's trivial and natural -- but as I said, the learning curve is no small thing. If Brandon's thing can get you over the hump in the project you're on, I'd use it. Don't trade an hour of workaround for two weeks of learning a new programming paradigm unless learning the new programming paradigm is the actual goal (and here I infer it isn't). But if you're going to be with WPF for the long haul, I'd seriously bite the MVVM bullet.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ok, thank you, in the end i want to learn MVVM, i just want to see if i can visualy achieve things faster (sort of deadline) and when i make these 15ish buttons to hide/show as they should i will read and try about MVVM

Comment: @Thomas If I had 15 buttons in MVVM, I'd have an ObservableCollection of some kind of cheapo ThingyItem class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has `Name`, `Content`, and `bool IsVisible` properties. Then I'd display those things as Buttons using an `ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate` with bindings for their properties, and when I wanted to hide one of them I'd look up the `ThingyItem` in the `ObservableCollection` and set its `IsVisible` property to `false` -- all of which sounds roughly like "blah blah blah" in Etruscan from the wrong end of the learning curve. It's easy I swear!